# Curvy arrow with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you show me how to draw this with TikZ?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Et voila!

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[rotate=-10] (0,0) -- (5,4) -- (5,2) to[bend right=10] (25,5) to[bend left=10] (5,-2) -- (5,-4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without TikZ. It needs some point adjustment to be more similar to the given arrow in the question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,5)
\pscustom*
{
    \pscurve(1,3.5)(2.5,3)(6,3)
    \pscurve(2.5,2.25)(1,2.5)
    \psline(1,2)(0,3)(1,4)  
    \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```